# Very Style CSS Mega Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am looking at creating a navigation menu similar in style to Very.co.uk

Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as where to start and best practices?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this is the basic idea...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hgZGS/

jQuery...

```
$('#menu span').hide();
$('#menu li').hover(function() {
```

```
var offset = $(this).offset();
$(this).find('span').css('marginLeft', offset.left + 'px');
$(this).find('span').show();

var offsetRight = offset.left + $(this).find('span').width();
var ww = $(window).width();
var fixed = offset.left + $(this).width() - $(this).find('span').width();

if (offsetRight > ww) {
    $(this).find('span').css('marginLeft', fixed + 'px');
}
else {
    $(this).find('span').css('marginLeft', offset.left + 'px');
}
```

}, function() {
    $(this).find('span').hide();
});

CSS...

```
#menu {
    margin: 20px;   
}
#menu LI {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
#menu SPAN {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
    left: 0px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

HTML...

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>The Quick<span>Quick</span></li>
    <li>Brown<span>Brown</span></li>
    <li>Fox<span>Fox</span></li>
    <li>Jumps<span>Jumps</span></li>
    <li>Over<span>Over</span></li>
    <li>Then<span>The</span></li>
    <li>Tall<span>Tall</span></li>
    <li>White<span>White</span></li>
    <li>Fence<span>Fence</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats exactly the sort of base I was looking to work from, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Mega Drop Down Menus w/ CSS & jQuery](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/)
Its got a good tutorial and a demo.

Answer (score 0):

best start is to make a structure like

```
<ul>
<li><a href="">Menu</a><div class="subnav">any popunder content</div></li>
...
</ul>
```

then, make <li> a relative left floating block and .subnav an absolute positioning:

```
ul li { float: left; display: block; position: relative }
ul li .subnav { display: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0 }
/* you may need to edit top and left to fit your needs */
```

then via css you can do:

```
ul li:hover .subnav { display: block }
```

and duplicate via jquery for old school browsers

```
$('ul li').hover(
  function() { $(this).find('.subnav').css('display', 'block') },
  function() { $(this).find('.subnav').css('display', 'none') }
);
```

that may be the beginning for your studies :)